# How to Import Metadata of feature classes with them into ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, xml, metadata

I have a database that has numerous feature classes of different types.  None of these feature classes have metadata.  I understand that when you import feature classes to a database, the metadata does not come with.  I'm trying to import metadata to features that have never had metadata and I'm not seeing a way to do this.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Server is your ArcSDE component from?  I ask because the metadata approach has changed in recent versions.

Comment: Our version is 10.1 and it is a 2 tier connection

Answer (score 1):

That is incorrect; if the SHP or other source feature does have the appropriate Metadata and you do a IMPORT into a ArcSDE database then the appropriate Metadata will load.
I do this myself as I refresh data every 90 days it it works like a charm.

Comment: What is appropriate metadata?  ISO or FGDC format or something else entirely?

Comment: ISO is the easiest and most minimal footprint, A good function would be to create yourself a template from ArcCatalog. Create a bogus layer, fill in the metadata for it then export it so you can have the XML file. Then you can copy this and modify for your various layers. Once named properly when you import the data should follow. This is our SOP.